# React Native project without TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I started learning React Native, created a project using React Native CLI, but it uses TypeScript by default. Can I somehow create a project using React Native CLI, but without TypeScript or do I need to just remove all TypeScript manually?

Comment: You can use .js instead of .tsx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 01:**
TypeScript is the default for new projects created with the React Native CLI. If you want to create a project without TypeScript, you'll need to remove TypeScript files and configurations manually from the generated project. There isn't a specific CLI option to exclude TypeScript during project creation.

**Solution 02:**
Other solution is that you can try previous versions of react native like

```
npx react-native init MyProject --version 0.70
```

It will create react native project with javascript instead of typescript template.

Answer (score 1):

From the 0.71 version of React-Native typescript is added by the default. More information [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/typescript#using-javascript-instead-of-typescript).

Of course, you can change the files extensions to `.js` and `.jsx` and uninstall unnecessary typescript packages. Nonetheless, I would suggest to use typescript though.